# how do I get mysql CASE or IF to skip a record?

Tags: mysql, sql, percona

I loop through a dataset, I use `CASE` to check if a condition (uut_status) is set to 'passed'. If that condition is set then I want the record.  If it isn't then I don't.

At the moment all records are coming back whether I want them or not. The ones I don't want are coming back with the values checked in the case statement set to null:

```
select CASE WHEN UUT_STATUS = 'passed' THEN  uut_serial_number END, 
    CASE WHEN UUT_STATUS = 'passed' THEN  uut_status END, 
    CASE WHEN UUT_STATUS = 'passed' THEN  min(START_DATE_TIME) END

from 
  uut_result 
where
 (START_DATE_TIME > '2016-06-16 00:00:00' AND START_DATE_TIME < '2016-06-16 23:59:59') and product_id=2513 and BATCH_SERIAL_NUMBER like "12 Initial Response Test"
```

group by uut_serial_number, uut_status, product_id
 order by uut_serial_number asc;

is returning:

```
SN123   Passed  2016-06-16 08:50:20
SN124   Passed  2016-06-16 16:46:57
NULL    NULL    NULL
SN126   Passed  2016-06-16 00:43:59
```

when what I want it to return is

```
SN123   Passed  2016-06-16 08:50:20
SN124   Passed  2016-06-16 16:46:57
SN126   Passed  2016-06-16 00:43:59
```

How do I simply exclude the records I don't want from the return set?

Clarification - take, for example SN456.  SN456 is tested at 9am.  It fails.  But, after tweaking, it's tested again at 9.30am and passes.
SN457 is tested at 9.05am.  It passes.

What we want is:

```
SN457 09:05:00
```

What we don't want is:

```
SN457 09:05:00
SN456 09:30:00
```

SN456 failed its first test and therefore is not to appear in the first pass result.

Hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `AND UUT_STATUS = 'passed'` in `WHERE` condition. No need for `CASE` at all.

---

Edit: according to your comment:

```
SELECT 
  (CASE WHEN UUT_STATUS = 'passed' THEN  uut_status END) as UUT_STATUS `,
...
GROUP BY uut_serial_number, uut_status, product_id
HAVING UUT_STATUS = 'passed'
ORDER BY uut_serial_number ASC
```

Comment: no, not working. It's returning the first test that passed. This is the problem I hit - I can get the first test that passed, but what I want is the first test the unit took *if* it passed.